# Is this bad if/else programming practice?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I have this if/else loop here in a function, and I just want to know if this is an 'acceptable' way to do things. It does what I want it to do but I think there must be a more elegant solution.

```
var signUpCheckAll = function(username, password, passwordconf, email){
    if (emptyChecker(username, password)) {
        if (emptyChecker(passwordconf, email)) {
            if (lengthChecker(password)) {
                if (passwordCheck(password, passwordconf)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Passwords don't match!");
                }
            }
            else{
                console.log("Password isn't long enough!");
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log("Some fields are empty!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) there is no loop. 2) it works, so you may want to ask this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: `emptyChecker` with 2 arguments? :/

Answer (score 3):

I personally (and possibly many others too) consider this much more readable:

```
if (!emptyChecker(username, password)) {  
    console.log("Some fields are empty!");
}
else if (!emptyChecker(passwordconf, email)) {
   //Where’s the message?
}
else if (!lengthChecker(password)) {
    console.log("Password isn't long enough!");
}
else if (!passwordCheck(password, passwordconf)) {
    console.log("Passwords don't match!");
}
else {
    return true;
}
```

I would also recommend renaming your functions. It is not clear what function name `passwordCheck` does. A function name should always include a verb representing the action or return of the function. `passwordsMatch` is way better. (You can then read the line as "else if (not) passwords (don’t) match".)